# Light control using java-jni

Tags: java, c

I am working on a project under which i am going to control lights of one floor of building through the server pc on the same floor using JAVA and C programming.I have almost designed the things but I want to check whether my design is upto the standards or not.

I would like to know if there are any such products/projects going on in the market,or any reasearch papers.

I am not asking about all those hobby project links,i want something that has been implemented on larger scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by controlling lights? On/off?
There are X-10 devices available in market, which can do such type of  things.
Most of home automation system uses those. They can easily communicate with PC.

You can go though this for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_%28industry_standard%29